# unoil-3.0.1.jar is giving "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" error

Tags: java, android, jar, jodconverter

I'm using jodconverter in my android app to convert doc files to pdf.
I get "**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**" when i include all the jar files including **unoil-3.0.1.jar.**
But if i remove unoil-3.0.1.jar that error won't be there.
But it is giving run time exception.
Here is my log:

```
05-28 07:00:49.360: D/CordovaLog(1380): calling converter
05-28 07:00:49.360: I/chromium(1380): [INFO:CONSOLE(44)] "calling converter", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (44)
05-28 07:00:51.580: D/PluginManager(1380): exec() call to unknown plugin: com.mindtree.native_phonegap.FileConverter
05-28 07:02:55.220: I/CordovaLog(1454): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
05-28 07:02:55.270: I/CordovaLog(1454): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
05-28 07:02:55.270: D/CordovaLog(1454): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
05-28 07:02:55.270: I/CordovaLog(1454): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
05-28 07:02:55.270: D/CordovaLog(1454): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
05-28 07:02:55.270: D/DroidGap(1454): DroidGap.onCreate()
05-28 07:02:55.430: V/WebViewChromium(1454): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper{b3d854a0}
05-28 07:02:55.470: I/chromium(1454): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
05-28 07:02:55.500: I/BrowserProcessMain(1454): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
05-28 07:02:55.750: E/chromium(1454): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
05-28 07:02:55.750: E/chromium(1454): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
05-28 07:02:55.750: E/chromium(1454): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
05-28 07:02:55.750: E/chromium(1454): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
05-28 07:02:55.750: E/chromium(1454): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
05-28 07:02:55.770: W/chromium(1454): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
05-28 07:02:55.890: D/dalvikvm(1454): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 81K, 5% free 2888K/3040K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
05-28 07:02:55.890: I/dalvikvm-heap(1454): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.490MB for 635812-byte allocation
05-28 07:02:56.000: D/dalvikvm(1454): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3508K/3664K, paused 84ms, total 84ms
05-28 07:02:56.080: D/CordovaWebView(1454): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
05-28 07:02:56.100: D/JsMessageQueue(1454): Set native->JS mode to 2
05-28 07:02:56.110: D/DroidGap(1454): DroidGap.init()
05-28 07:02:56.130: D/CordovaWebView(1454): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-28 07:02:56.130: D/PluginManager(1454): init()
05-28 07:02:56.140: D/CordovaWebView(1454): >>> loadUrlNow()
05-28 07:02:56.290: D/DroidGap(1454): Resuming the App
05-28 07:02:56.350: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1454): Ignore this event
05-28 07:02:56.430: D/gralloc_goldfish(1454): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-28 07:02:56.590: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(1454): Ignore this event
05-28 07:02:57.170: D/DroidGap(1454): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-28 07:02:58.740: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1454): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.json
05-28 07:03:01.440: D/CordovaNetworkManager(1454): Connection Type: 3g
05-28 07:03:01.450: D/DroidGap(1454): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
05-28 07:03:01.450: D/CordovaNetworkManager(1454): Connection Type: 3g
05-28 07:03:01.510: D/DroidGap(1454): onMessage(spinner,stop)
05-28 07:03:03.170: D/Cordova(1454): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-28 07:03:03.170: D/DroidGap(1454): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-28 07:03:42.210: D/CordovaLog(1454): calling converter
05-28 07:03:42.210: I/chromium(1454): [INFO:CONSOLE(44)] "calling converter", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (44)
05-28 07:03:44.610: D/FileConverter Plugin(1454): in native fn
05-28 07:03:44.830: E/dalvikvm(1454): **Could not find class 'com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader', referenced from method com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.getDesktop**
05-28 07:03:44.830: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1010 (Lcom/sun/star/frame/XComponentLoader;) in Lcom/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/connection/AbstractOpenOfficeConnection;
05-28 07:03:44.830: D/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0016
05-28 07:03:44.830: E/dalvikvm(1454): Could not find class 'com.sun.star.ucb.XFileIdentifierConverter', referenced from method com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.getFileContentProvider
05-28 07:03:44.830: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1318 (Lcom/sun/star/ucb/XFileIdentifierConverter;) in Lcom/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/connection/AbstractOpenOfficeConnection;
05-28 07:03:44.830: D/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0016
05-28 07:03:44.850: I/dalvikvm(1454): DexOpt: access denied from Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory; to field Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;.SINGLETON
05-28 07:03:44.850: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4488 (SINGLETON) in Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
05-28 07:03:44.850: D/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
05-28 07:03:44.850: I/dalvikvm(1454): DexOpt: access denied from Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory; to field Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;.SINGLETON
05-28 07:03:44.850: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4488 (SINGLETON) in Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
05-28 07:03:44.850: D/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001d
05-28 07:03:45.120: W/System.err(1454): java.net.ConnectException: connection failed: socket,host=localhost,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8100): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
05-28 07:03:45.120: W/System.err(1454):     at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.connect(AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.java:79)
05-28 07:03:45.120: W/System.err(1454):     at com.example.pdfexplorer.FileConverter.execute(FileConverter.java:33)
05-28 07:03:45.120: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:85)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:66)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:224)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:51)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 07:03:45.130: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1295 (Lcom/sun/star/task/ErrorCodeIOException;)
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xe
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY:  rejected Lcom/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/converter/OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;.loadAndExport (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x000e
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1454): VFY:  rejected Lcom/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/converter/OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;.loadAndExport (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/dalvikvm(1454): Verifier rejected class Lcom/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/converter/OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;
05-28 07:03:45.150: W/System.err(1454): java.lang.VerifyError: com/artofsolving/jodconverter/openoffice/converter/OpenOfficeDocumentConverter
05-28 07:03:45.160: W/System.err(1454):     at com.example.pdfexplorer.FileConverter.execute(FileConverter.java:40)
05-28 07:03:45.170: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:85)
05-28 07:03:45.170: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:66)
05-28 07:03:45.170: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:224)
05-28 07:03:45.180: W/System.err(1454):     at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:51)
05-28 07:03:45.180: W/System.err(1454):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
05-28 07:03:45.180: W/System.err(1454):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
05-28 07:03:45.180: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-28 07:03:45.190: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 07:03:45.190: W/System.err(1454):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-28 07:03:45.240: D/CordovaLog(1454): Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
05-28 07:03:45.240: I/chromium(1454): [INFO:CONSOLE(857)] "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.7.0.js (857)
```

I searched all the links for that Dalvik error, nothing is working for me.
Any work-around for this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually, this means that the JAR is using something that does not exist in Android. You could try adding the source for this JAR to your project directly, rather than using the JAR, as you may get more information (or, you may get a clean compile).

Comment: Thanku CommonsWare, but how can i find the source ?? It's an external JAR file.

Comment: Poke around the OpenOffice site, I guess.

Comment: Did you find solution? Please tell us